# SharePoint 2019 Convert-SPWebApplication fails to migrate any users

Tags: sharepoint-server, adfs, migration

I'm attempting to migrate the users on a web application in SP 2019 from Windows claims to SAML/ADFS claims (with UPN for the identity claim). Both authentication methods are enabled and working on the web application (I can manually add users and authenticate with either). The Migrate-SPWebApplication command completes without error, just a warning that the conversion and most of the users were migrated successfully, yet no users are actually migrated. When looking through the ULS logs I see the following for each of the failed migrations:

```
User SPPrincipalInfo doesn't seem to have an user principal name value. User: 'XXX\XXX', ID: '-1'
Couldn't build a claim for user to perform migration because user likely does not have UPN set in AD. Type: 'User', Old Name: 'i:0#.w|xxx\xxx', Old Key 'i:0).w|s-1-5-21-xxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxx-xxxxx', Mapped Name: '', Mapped Key: '', Mapped Title '', Mapped Email ''..
```

All users have UPNs defined in AD, and they are synced with the user profile service without issue. Is there something else I'm missing here?